# Oracle - SQL - Count multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Using Oracle 10G

Say for example I have a table with three fields in it, I'd like one query which selects the counts of each column where they are not null. Field name

```
----------------------------------
| strTest1 | strTest2 | strTest3 |
----------------------------------
```

I know how to get the count of each one individually:

```
select count(*) from tablename where strTest1 is not null
```

but I'd like to know if it's possible to do this within one query for all 3 fields.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the nulls? Or not nulls?

Comment: @Thilo as specified in the quesiton, not nulls. The answer below works as expected.

Comment: Re: "as specified in the question": The code example does the opposite, though.

Comment: @Thilo OMG, so sorry, thanks for pointing out this mistake. Sorry for any confusion caused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(STRTEST1), COUNT(STRTEST2), COUNT(STRTEST3) FROM YOUR_TABLE
```